# How I can update session in server side

Tags: authentication, session, next.js, next-auth

How I can update session in server side using authV5 in nextjs latest update

I tried :

import { update } from "@/auth

But the update not in auth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In authV5, you need to import the update method when you create your NextAuth instance:

auth.ts:

```js
export const { auth, signIn, signOut, update } = NextAuth({ ... })
```

You can then import it into another component as you are doing:

```js
import {update} from "@/auth"
```